# Setting Infinite start date in ionic date picker components

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, datepicker, calendar, ionic3

I am using a date picker components for ionic2 ／ionic3 (https://github.com/HsuanXyz/ion2-calendar)
My problem is that I can enable days before today, I enabled days after today with no end using code below, but it disable whole days!

optionsRange: CalendarComponentOptions = {
    from:0,
    to:0,
  };

When I use code below, it enables dates from today!

optionsRange: CalendarComponentOptions = {
    from:new Date(),
    to:0,
  };

Can you please tell me how I can enable days before today?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem, You have to use CalendarComponentOptions as follows

optionsRange: CalendarComponentOptions = {
    from:1,
    to:0
};
Remark: Do not forget to remove "," at the final component option. For example change to: 0,} to to :0 } in your code

Comment: It Works great! Thank you so much!